# Web API filter data by user permission

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Which is the best way to filter a data list from data base using user's permission?

For example:
I have a controller that returns a list of cars with all their properties, but I don't want to tell the controller which cars I want. The controller must check which cars the user,  that is requesting, can see, filter the data list and send only the permitted cars. So user A see only car 1, 2, 5, user B cars 2, 3, 4, 5 and it goes. A car it's not specific to a unique user, it may have multiple users linked to.

I'm using asp.net identity and entity framework

-- edit --

I've been recently searching for and maybe claims could be my solution. But how I use claims to filter data and only bring the items that user has permission?

Please anyone help

-- edit 2 --

I'm adding an example code

```
public class CarModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; }
  // and others
}
```

controller:

```
public class CarsController
{
  [Authorize]
  public List<CarModel> GetCars ()
  {
    // get current user permission and return only cars that current user can see
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.  It's hard to help with code we can't see.

Comment: so how are your users linked to your cars? It's not clear. Via database records?

Comment: Yeah. Imagine an "users management"  that you can setup which user is linked to each car. I guess this will be stored on the database. But that's my question, which is the best way to do that. Using claims?

Comment: Do I have to get users claims in the controller action like: `var carsId = user.claims("cars");` then I get all cars Id that user can see so I return a query which car Id is in the list carsId. That's what I am asking